# Razor and ASP.NET: the right way to test whether a record exists and use its fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have the following code in a cshtml  file to retrieve a record (has to be only record) and display its record:

```
@{
    //id is already obtained at this point
    var db = Database.Open("myConnection");
    var query = "select * from my_record where id= " + id;
}

@foreach (var row in db.Query(query))
{
    <span>@row.title</span>

}
```

As you can see, I use foreach loop as a test to see if there is any record. In my case, there is ONLY one record for sure. What is the right way to test whether a record exists instead of using foreach?

**UPDATE**

I understand the controller, etc. I hope to have a quick solution for a VERY simple situation. It is a simple page for illustration only. I am not ready to build a three-tier web application. It is ASP.NET Web Pages (and not ASP.NET MVC). Thanks.

Regards and thanks.

Comment: All of this belongs to controller, if not even DAL under it. Please avoid data retrieval in markup files

Comment: Andrei, thanks for your suggestion. I have to use it the way as is now

Comment: You pick all wrong turns - code in controller vs. view, parametrized SQL queries vs. `string.Concat`, and likley answer `foreach` vs. [Enumerable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) :(

Comment: @curious1, sorry, just out of general curiosity - why are you under such constraint?

Comment: var query = "select count(*) from my_record where id= " + id; Then check for a number greater than zero.

Comment: It is a simple page for illustration only. I am not ready to buildi a three-tier web application.

Comment: Also, it is not clear - do you really need just a "exists/does not exist" answer? Or retrieve just one record and avoid foreach?

Comment: Andrei, I need to test whether the record exists and use its fields if there is. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QuerySingle`. Afaik it returns `null` if nothing is found, so:

```
@{
    //id is already obtained at this point
    var db = Database.Open("myConnection");
    var query = "select * from my_record where id= " + id;
    var record = db.QuerySingle(query);
}

@if (record != null)
{
    <span>@record.title</span>

}
```

Comment: Andrei: what is RecordTypeHere? It just a row, not corresponding to any class.

Comment: @curious1, this is just me confused. Already removed it, sorry

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm!!! I am not a C#/Razor expert, but I have to build something simple and quick just for illustration. I did LOT of programming in other platforms.

Comment: @curious1, if all this is just proof-of-concept work, then no problem. Glad it helped

Comment: It helped beautifully. I know my old solution works, but that is just not clean or right.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not really. You are returning the entire record, and there is no need for that. You can modify your query to be the following:

```
var sql = "select count(*) from my_record where id= " + id;
```

This will return the count of records matching the `where` clause. You simply check if the result is `!= 1` to determine if it does not exist.

That all said, unless you are using ASP.NET Web Pages (and *not* ASP.NET MVC) you should move this data code to your controller.

**edit**

> What is the right way to test whether a record exists instead of using foreach?

That depends on the result of `db.Query(query)`. a simple implementation would be

```
var results = db.Query(query);
if(results.Count() == 0)
{
// does not exist
}
```

Comment: Nate, your sql only gets the count of records. I still need to access the record's fields if it exists. It is ASP.NET Web Pages (and not ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: You asked if it was the best way to check if it exists, not if it exists and then display it. If you need to check if it exists and display it, then your query should be OK (presuming you need all the fields)

Answer (score 1):

Long comment:

[Queryable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.queryable.single%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) along with LINQ to SQL query is possible approach - it will generate proper SQL request for you and avoid potentially querying more than one item.

If you know that you need at most one item - restrict maximum number of elements (i.e. to 2) so even if DB have multiple matching rows you query at most several (more than one since you seem to want to verify if there is zero or one rows).